Semiring of f.d. representations of a semisimple Lie algebra
Let $\mathfrak g$ be a finite dimensional complex semisimple Lie algebra. I have read in [Fulton-Harris, Thm 23.24] and  [Samelson, sec 3.5 Thm A] that the representation ring  $\mathrm{Rep}(\mathfrak g)$ is isomorphic to a polynomial ring on the variables $u_1, \ldots , u_n$, where $u_i$'s are the classes of the irreducible representations $V(\lambda_i)$ with highest weights the fundamental dominant weights $\lambda_i$, the isomorphism being the  ring homomorphism $$\mathbb Z [u_1, \ldots, u_n] \to \mathrm{Rep}(\mathfrak g) $$ which maps $u_i $ to $V(\lambda_i)$.
Checking the argument given in the books, I believe that it is not necessary to pass to the Grothendieck completion of the semiring $\widetilde{\mathrm{Rep}} (\mathfrak g)$ of (isomorphism classes of) finite-dimensional irreducible representations, but instead one gets an isomorphism at the semiring level. That is, that the semiring map
$$\mathbb N [u_1, \ldots, u_n] \to \widetilde{\mathrm{Rep}} (\mathfrak g) $$ which maps $u_i $ to $V(\lambda_i)$ is already an isomorphism (and the former map is obtained by applying the Grothendieck construction to the latter).
Is this correct?
